# Unable to traverse the array. For loop is failing

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

I am taking a subarray from a service call and trying to print array values. 
I am able to fetch the values and store in an array. But when I try to traverse the array using Extjs tpl loop. It is failing at for condition
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrcwH.png)
I have checked
1. control is going till tpl, anything before for is getting printed
2. array has 4 records.

```
initComponent: function() {
var me = this;
var dataItems= me.loadData();
this.items = [{                     
    xtype : 'dataview',             
    store: 'proceduresDateGroupedByCodeGroupSid',
    multiSelect: true,
    trackOver: true,
    overItemCls: 'lab-result-detail-row ',
    itemSelector : '.item-selector',
    padding : '0 0 0 0',

    tpl: new PD.view.component.CTemplate(
         '<div>HELLO</div>',
        '<tpl for="dataItems">',                        
        '<div>hello</div>', 
        '<div>{this.formatDate},
         '</div>', 
        '</tpl>',
```

Ideally it should print "hello" 4 times.

Comment: show `me.loadData()` code. Im guessing its an async action and thats probably why it isnt working

Comment: loadData: function() {
        var me = this;       
        dataItems= me.config._rowContext.record.data.childDTOs;
        return dataItems;}

Answer (score 0):

Your ItemSelector is appointing to a class called item-selector, but in your tpl you don't have a div with this class, instead, try this.

```
 itemSelector:'div.item-selector',
 tpl: new PD.view.component.CTemplate(
         '<div>HELLO</div>',
        '<tpl for=".">',                        
        '<div classs="item-selector">hello</div>', 
        '<div>{this.formatDate},
         '</div>', 
        '</tpl>',
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rl0)

Comment: Yes, it worked. But it prints "hello" only once. There are 4 items in array. it should loop 4 times...any idea ?

Comment: Don't know how your store is structured, check out the fiddle for an example, maybe the problem is in `{this.formatDate}`

Comment: It prints `hello` only once because `'<div>HELLO</div>',` is before than `'<tpl for=".">',` and `'</tpl>', `

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to your not specifying class="item-selector" as shown in the code below

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            data: [{
                name: 'lorem',
                value: '01'
            }, {
                name: 'ipsum',
                value: '02'
            }, {
                name: 'dolor',
                value: '03'
            }, {
                name: 'sit',
                value: '04'
            }]

        });
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            width: 200,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'dataview',
                store: store,
                 itemSelector: 'div.item-selector',
                tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<tpl for=".">',
                    '<div>HELLO</div>',
                    '<div>hello</div>',
                    '<div style="border-bottom: thin solid black">{name}</div>',
                    '</tpl>'
                )
            }]

        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ro7) for above code.

The problem was as stated by @norbeq in the answer given by @Matheus Hatje. The placement of your

> HELLO

Being above the `**<tpl for=".">**` It is not contained within the for look so it would only print once.